# Why I'm missing events on my Log Analytics Query?

Tags: azure-log-analytics, kql

On query below , I can only see data from hours 3 up 8.. all data for other timeframes are missing.
The data is being generated by Azure SQL log analytics configuration where I can't see anything missing.
Any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

[image: Kusto Query]
[image: Log Analytics Collection]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the events are missing for the other times, since you can see the events between time 3 to 8.

You'd better check if there are logs in the other time. Azure log analytics does not abandon your logs.

Answer (score 0):

According to MS support, I'm hitting the daily cap limit and also free tier wasn't available on my region.